# Extract arrays followed with corresponding matches

Tags: perl

I am very new to Perl. I need to extract arrays and print in the columns below. The tricky part is that each word has different pronunciation types ( which is specified in P or S) and each type is associated with its corresponding pronunciation and syllable shape.

I tried to extract by using array [ ], but the codes are fairly long. Is there a more efficient way to code it?

Input (the data is located in celex corpus). The following is one example of the thousands of lines.

```
31259\open\635\3\P\5-p@n\[VV][CVC]\[@U][p@n]\P\5-pH\[VV][CS]\[@U][pn,]\S\5-pF\[VV][CS]\[@U][pm,]
........
........
```

My Output needs to look like this:

```
WordForm   Frequency    Type      Pronunciation SyllableShape 

open         635       P.          [@U] [p@n]      [VV] [CVC]

open         635       P.          [@U] [pn,]          [VV] [CS] 

open         635       S           [@U] [pm,]          [VV] [CS] 

...

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you determine if there is a `.` after the `P` but, assuming these are all 4 element groups and a 5 element header, how about an `awk` solution?

```
awk -F '\' 'BEGIN{ print "WordForm Frequency Type Pronunciation Syllableshape"}{
     for (i=5;i<=NF;i+=4) print $2, $3, $i, $(i+3), $(i+2)
}' file | column -t
```

Output

```
WordForm  Frequency  Type  Pronunciation  Syllableshape
open      635        P     [@U][p@n]      [VV][CVC]
open      635        P     [@U][pn,]      [VV][CS]
open      635        S     [@U][pm,]      [VV][CS]
```

**Edit**

As per the post below, and just for fun (because I have never even looked at `perl` for scripting purposes before last night) I have hammered the above loop into a `perl` script that seems to function. I am sure there is a lot wrong with the below because it was cobbled together from scratch with no knowledge. So if it is horribly poor coding, then please don't comment or criticise, just post the correct way to do it for my education too.

```
#!/bin/perl

open(my $filehandle, '<', './file')
    or die "Unable to open file, $!";
    print "WordForm  Frequency  Type  Pronunciation  Syllableshape\n";
    while (<$filehandle>) { 
        chomp($_);
        @c = split (/\\/, $_);
        for ($i=4;$i<=(@c-4);$i+=4) {
            print "@c[1] @c[2] @c[$i] @c[$i+3] @c[$i+2]\n";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
close($filehandle)
    or warn "Unable to close the file handle: $!";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If certain line contains 14 types of pronunciations (P or S) which will generate 14 rows of the 5 headers.  Will the code still work?

Comment: It iterates over the entire length of each line until it reaches the end before going on to the next line, so yes, it should do.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, I tried a different approach by adopting your concept but using loop and "for" in perl. But it won't run.  Can you check if there is logic issue in my codes so it will not iterate.

Comment: Here is the code.

open my $f, '<' ,"/corpora/celex release 2/english/epl/epl.cd " or die "No file!";

open my $o, '>', "epl.cd";

print $o "WordForm\tFrequency\tType\tPronounciation\tSyllableShape\n";


while(<$f>) 

   {

   $line = $_;

   chomp($line);


   @Array = split(/\. ?/,$line)


for($i = 5; $i <=$numbers_of_arrays) {


         print $o “$Array[2]” . "\t" .  “$Array[3]” . "\t" . “$i” . “\t” . “$[i+3]”.  “\t” . “$[$i+2”. 

         $i = $i +4;

         }

print  $o "\n";

}

close($f);

close($o);

Comment: I must admit I don't know `perl` but last night and just for fun I managed to get an MWE together but it fell over at the newline. Will post what I have for you and maybe you can fix it.

Comment: Just looked at your `perl` code. Issues that I can see. Syntax wrong in the open statement; why print `$o`? You open `$o` and then try to read from `$f`! Your split statement is not terminated with `;`; the `for` loop starts at 5 because you want the 5th field but  `perl` starts the array index at 0 not 1 so the loop counter should start at 4 to point at the 5th field; you don't need to `close $f` because you never opened it.....  nuff said?

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the perl script a bit. This "script" can be called with `perl script file`.

```
print "WordForm Frequency  Type  Pronunciation  Syllableshape\n";
while (<>) {
        chomp;
        @c = split(/\\/);
        for ($i=4; $i<$#c; $i+=4) {
            print "$c[1] $c[2]";
            print " $c[$i] $c[$i+3] $c[$i+2]\n";
        }
}
```

`$i<$#c;` instead of `$i<@c-4;`: I left out that "safety" minus 4 (matters only if records are broken).

`$#c` is the array `@c` as scalar value i.e. last index.

---

The only difference to awk (`i=5`) is the `$i=4`, because the first element is `$c[0]` in perl.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the codes above but wasn't successful because Perl did not accept math such as $c [$I + 3]. I modified your codes and the system gave me ssf syntax errors. I am showing my codes below.

Comment: Syntax error at epl.cd line 26 near “4;”

Syntax error at epl.cd line 26 near “4)  ”

Unrecognized character \xE2; marked by < = HERE after $c [1] < = HERE near column 59 at epl.cd line 29


while(<$f>) 

   {

  $line = $_;

  chomp($line);

  @c = split(/ /, $line)

for($i = 4; $j = $i + 3; $k = $i + 2; $i <=$#c; $i+=4)  {

print $o $c[1] . "\t" .  $c[2] . "\t" . $c[$i] . “\t” . $c[$j].  “\t” . $c[$k] .  “\n”;. 

         }  

   }

close($f);

close($o);